How large can $\mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4]$ get?
Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $[0,\infty)$ and $X_1, \dots, X_4 \sim \mu$ independent. Then what can be said about the probability that $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4$?
More precisely, what is the value of
$$\tag{1}\sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4] \quad ?$$
Here's what I know:

Numerically, taking $\mu$ to be a Gamma distribution at parameter $\alpha \approx 0.5$ gives a value of $\approx 0.3080$ (clearly independently of scale). This is the largest value I've found among the distributions I've tried.
In the other direction, a symmetrization argument gives an upper bound of $\frac{1}{2}$ on (1).
Indeed putting each of the four variables on the right-hand side gives four versions of the inequality $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4$, all with the same probability. At most two of these can be satisfied jointly (since if three of them held jointly, then adding them produces a contradiction). Then the upper bound of $\frac{1}{2}$ follows by exchangeability: if four symmetric events are such that at most two can happen jointly, then the probability of each is at most $\frac{1}{2}$. (Think of the induced distribution on $\{0,1\}^4$, which must be supported on sequences with at most two $1$'s.)
There are several similar problems which I've been able to solve:
$$\sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 < X_3] = \frac{1}{3}, \qquad \sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < X_4 + X_5] = \frac{2}{5}.$$
In both of these cases, the supremum is approached by a sequence of distributions that are uniform on a large finite set with exponential spacing, so that $+$ effectively becomes $\max$. But such distributions do not approach the supremum in (1).


For a distribution to be globally optimal a necessary condition is that it be locally optimal, which in particular implies that the function sending $Y$ to $ 3 \mathbb P[X_1 + X_2 + Y < 3 X_4] + \mathbb P [X_1+X_2+X_3< Y]$ is maximized for $Y$ in the support of the distribution. I didn't check rigorously but I'm pretty sure this is not true for the Gamma distribution, so it can't literally be the optimum, although it could be close.

What do you mean by "a symmetrization argument shows that..."?

@DrewBrady: thanks for asking, as this made me realize that what I wrote wasn't quite right; I believe that $\sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 3 X_4]$ is actually $3/4$, but can't quite prove it yet. I've corrected the argument now. It may be a bit terse, so let me know in case that you'd like me to expand.

I've updated my answer with an improved upper bound.

I believe the probability is at least $\approx0.343$.
Let $\mu_n$ be a probability measure giving
$q_n = P_n[ X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2X_4]$.
Consider now $(Y_i)_{i\le 4}$ Bernoulli$(p)$. The $Y_i$'s produce the desired inequality with an inclusive $\le$ with probability
\begin{align}
I+II+III &= P[ \text{binomial}(3, p) \le 1] P[Y_4=1] 
\\&\quad+ P[ \text{binomial}(3, p) = 2] P[Y_4=1] 
\\&\quad+ (1-p)^4.
\end{align}
But the problem requires a strict inequality, for which the second and third terms are lost. We can boost this binomial scheme by using $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ from $\mu_n$, independently $Y_i\sim{}$Bernoulli$(p)$ as above, and set
$$Z_i = t X_i + Y_i.$$
for some $t>0$ very small. Assuming that the support of $\mu_n$ is bounded, we can always choose $t>0$ small enough so that the first term is unchanged, while the second term and third terms become strict inequality with independent probability $q_n$:
$$
q_{n+1} = P[Z_1+Z_2+Z_3 < 2Z_4]
=
P[ \text{binomial}(3, p) \le 1] P[Y_4=1] 
+ q_n\Big(
P[ \text{binomial}(3, p) = 2] P[Y_4=1] 
+ (1-p)^4\Big).
$$
This defines two polynomial $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ of order $4$ in $p\in[0,1]$ such that
$$
q_{n+1} = f(p) + q_n g(p).
$$
Consider the fixed-point $q_\infty$ defined by
$$
q_{\infty} = 
f(p)
+ q_{\infty}
g(p).
$$
We can reach a large $q_\infty$ by maximizing
$$
M = \max_{p\in[0,1]} \frac{f(p)}{(1-g(p))_+}.
$$
If I am not mistaken, $f(p)= ((1-p)^3 + 3(1-p)^2p )p$
while $g(p) = 3p^2(1-p)p + (1-p)^4$.
The maximum is reached at $p^* \approx 0.404$ giving $M\approx 0.343$.
We now set $p=p^*$ for this maximizer, and perform this procedure, starting from some discrete distribution $q$ (e.g., Bernoulli($p^*$)). Since $g(p^*)\in(0,1)$, the sequence $q_n$ converges to $M\approx 0.343$.
Edit: using Will's explicit formula with $t=0.1$, with $n=30$ terms  confirm a probability of around $0.343$:
[14]: import numpy as np
  ...: 
  ...: p = 0.404
  ...: t = 0.1
  ...: powers = np.arange(30)
  ...: ts = (t ** powers)[None, None, :]
  ...: 
  ...: bs = np.random.binomial(1, p, size=(100000, 4, 30))
  ...: ys = np.sum(ts * bs, axis=-1)
  ...: (np.sum(ys[:, :-1], axis=1) <  2 * ys[:, -1]).mean()
[14]: 0.34353


It might be clearer to definine the distribution all at once as $X_i = Y_{i,1} + t Y_{i,2} + t^2 Y_{i,3} + \dots$ where $Y_{i,j}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli's with the same probability $p$ and $t$ a very small constant. Then $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4$ if and only if for some $i$ we have $Y_{1,i} + Y_{2,i} + Y_{3,i} < 2 Y_{4,i}$ and for all $j<i$ we have $Y_{1,j} + Y_{2,j} + Y_{3,j} < 2 Y_{4,j}$. One can derive your $f(p)/ (1-g(p))$ formula from this.

Thanks. With the explicit definition as a sum, simulations confirm around $3.3-3.4$.

In the cases where Tobias Fritz mentioned already finding the optimal value, this procedure (essentially) gets it: It's asymptotically approached here in the limit as $p$ goes to $0$. So it's possible this could be optimal here as well, although I would like to check local optimality also.

Nice! Applying this method with $Y_{i,j} \sim \frac{1}{2} \delta_0 + \frac{1}{6} \delta_2 + \frac{1}{3} \delta_3$, I actually get a probability of $\approx 0.365$. I will try to push this some further and then write another answer on how I came up with this choice.

I'm in the process of writing this up as a paper for an expository journal. In case that you're interested in coauthorship @jlewk, just shoot me an email! (Iif not, I'll of course still attribute this idea to you.)

Edit Dec 2024: Pierre C Bellec and I have written this preprint about the problem, giving improved bounds of
$$0.4 \le \sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4] \le 0.422.$$
This is based on the methods of both the present answers and on mixed-integer linear programming methods for solving the maximal feasible subsystem problem. We have some evidence for the conjecture that the lower bound of $0.4$ is the exact value.

In this answer, I will derive the following improved bounds:
$$0.367 \approx \frac{208}{567} \le \sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4] \le \frac{7}{15} \approx 0.467.$$
In the remarks at the end, I will sketch how this derivation is an instance of a general algorithm producing a sequence of bounds applicable to all problems of this type, and which converges to the exact value in the limit. (Unfortunately without further tricks, the algorithm has too high complexity to be useful in practice.)

Lower bound: Start with $\mu = \frac{1}{2} \delta_0 + \frac{1}{6} \delta_5 + \frac{1}{3} \delta_9$. Then some tedious calculations show that
$$\mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4] = \frac{26}{81}, \qquad \mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 2 X_4] = \frac{1}{8}.$$
Therefore applying the trick from jlewk's answer achieves
$$\mathbf{P}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < 2 X_4] = \frac{26/81}{1-1/8} = \frac{208}{567}.$$
I have no doubt that further tweaking can still improve this value.

Upper bound: Let's consider an extension of the argument for the upper bound of $\frac{1}{2}$ given in the question. To this end, consider independent $X_1, \dots, X_6 \sim \mu$. Then their joint distribution is invariant under permutations, and in particular the probability
$$\mathbf{P}[X_i + X_j + X_k < 2 X_\ell]$$
is independent of the choice of the indices as long as these are all distinct. I will refer to the $X_i + X_j + X_k < 2 X_\ell$ as "versions" of the original inequality, so there are $6 \cdot \binom{5}{3} = 60$ versions.
If $N$ denotes the maximal number of versions that can be jointly satisfied, then I claim that $\frac{N}{60}$ is an upper bound on the original problem. Indeed considering whether each inequality holds defines a distribution on $\{0,1\}^{60}$, where the probability of each sequence with more than $N$ many $1$s is zero. The claim then follows by the fact that the symmetry group acts transitively on the components of $\{0,1\}^{60}$.
Thus the remaining problem is to prove $N = 28$. To this end, it helps to assume without loss of generality that $X_1 \le \dots \le X_6$, and consider which quadruples $(i,j,k,\ell)$ can appear among the valid versions of the inequality. Let us assume $i < j < k$ without loss of generality and keep these fixed. Then $\ell > j$ is necessary, since otherwise we get $X_j \ge X_\ell$ and therefore
$$X_i + X_j + X_k \ge X_i + 2 X_\ell \ge 2 X_\ell,$$
which is exactly the negation of the desired inequality. From $\ell > j$ it follows that the number of possible $\ell$'s for a given triple $(i,j,k)$ is at most $5 - j$.
Enumerating thus the number of possible $\ell$ for each of the $20$ triples $(i,j,k)$ results in $30$ candidate quadruples $(i,j,k,\ell)$. In other words, we get $30$ version which are such that any jointly feasible set of versions is a subset of this one, modulo permutations of variables.
In order to conclude $N \le 28$, it is thus enough to find two disjoint subsets of these $30$ inequalities which are jointly infeasible in combination with $0 \le X_1 \le \dots \le X_6$. In fact, this holds already for the subsystem
$$X_1 + X_2 + X_6 < 2 X_3,$$
$$X_1 + X_3 + X_6 < 2 X_4,$$
$$X_3 + X_4 + X_5 < 2 X_6.$$
Indeed using $X_4 \le X_5$ and adding these inequalities produces the desired contradiction by $X_1, X_2 \ge 0$. A second such subsystem is
$$X_1 + X_2 + X_5 < 2 X_3,$$
$$X_1 + X_4 + X_5 < 2 X_6,$$
$$X_2 + X_3 + X_6 < 2 X_4,$$
$$X_3 + X_4 + X_6 < 2 X_5.$$
Therefore we have $N \le 28$, and this gives an upper bound of $\frac{28}{60} = \frac{7}{15}$.
On the other hand, $N = 28$ is achieved by
$$X_1 = X_2 = 0, \qquad X_3 = 4, \qquad X_4 = 5, \qquad X_5 = X_6 = 7.$$

Additional thoughts:

The determination of $N$ is a problem in extremal combinatorics. In general, determining the maximal number of jointly satisfiable inequalities is known as the maximum feasible subsystem problem, and it is NP-hard in general. This suggests that also determining $N$ in other cases may be challenging. It feels similar to hypergraph Turán problems.

It's not hard to see that the proof of the upper bound is an instance of a general method for deriving upper bounds on such probabilities based on exchangeability: for $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, consider how many versions of the inequality can be satisfied jointly. The fraction of these is then an upper bound on the desired quantity, and this is computable at least in theory.
I believe that these upper bounds are tight as $n \to \infty$, and Will Sawin has given a simple proof of this in the comments for the case at hand. I'd expect the method and its proof of correctness to apply generally to all analogous problems of the form $\sup_\mu \mathbf{P}[\sum_{i=1}^k a_i X_i > 0]$.

The idea behind Will's proof is to construct a distribution $\mu$ from the solution of a maximal feasible subsystem as the uniform distribution on the values of the variables and to use this as a lower bound. This way of thinking is also how I had found the $\mu = \frac{1}{2} \delta_0 + \frac{1}{6} \delta_5 + \frac{1}{3} \delta_9$ which appears in the new lower bound.



Running some linear programs with the 30 inequalities that arise in the evaluation of the upper bound suggests that that system is actually infeasible, in which case we'd get an improved upper bound of $29/60$. It must be possible to turn this into a relatively concise human-readable proof, but I haven't done this yet.

I think the proof that the exchangeability upper bound is sharp is relatively easy: If there exist $n$ values $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $a$ of the $4 \binom{n}{4}$ possible versions of the inequality plugging in $4$ of the $n$ values are satisfied, then the probability distribution which takes each of the values $x_1,\dots,x_n$ with probability $1/n$ satisfies the inequality with probability at least $6 a /n^4$ which is asymptotic to the upper bound $a/ (4 \binom{n}{4})$ as $n\to\infty$.

Right @WillSawin, good point! I was thinking that a compactness argument may be needed, but considering lower bounds at the same time is a clever way to avoid that.

To get $N=29$ we know one of the three inequalities you stated must fail which means all the other inequalities must succeed. This gives $3$ sets of $29$ inequalities to check joint satisfiability for, which doesn't seem too hard to check by linear programming.

@WillSawin: I agree, I just haven't seen the added benefit in squeezing out another 1/60 :)

This is a fascinating problem! I think the 2/5 lower bound (Conjecture 5.1 in the preprint) can be improved to
$$\sup_\mu \mathbb{P}_{\mu^{\otimes 4}}[X_1+X_2+X_3 <2 X_4] \geq 0.400695.$$
In brief, let $\mu_\varepsilon$ be the distribution of $\varepsilon^G (1-\varepsilon^U)$, where $G\sim\operatorname{Geometric}(1-0.474346)$ and $U\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0, 1)$ are independent, and take $\varepsilon \to 0^+$. (Numerically sampling from this distribution as $\varepsilon$ gets small requires some care, because floating-point representations have a catastrophic loss of absolute precision in the $1-\varepsilon^U$ term.) This comes from optimizing the probability mass at 0 in the construction of $\mu$ in the proof of Proposition 4.1, decreasing the mass from $p = \mu(\{0\}) = 1/2$ to $p_\text{max} \approx 0.474346$ (dump the excess mass to the rest of the measure proportionally).
In general, let $\{\nu_i\}_{i=1}^k$ be $k$ probability measures on a common space and consider the problem of optimizing an expectation among the convex combinations $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \nu_i$. The expectation (when it exists) of any measurable function $f$ of an $n$-element iid sample from $\mu$ can be decomposed (with multi-index notation $\newcommand{\v}{\boldsymbol} \v{\alpha} \in \mathbb{N}^k$) as
\begin{align}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \mathbb{E} [f(\v{X}) \mid \v{X}\sim\mu^{\otimes n}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\mathopen{}\left[\mathbb{E} [f(\v{M}\v{X}) \mid \v{X}\sim\v{\nu}^{\otimes \v{\alpha}}] \mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} \v{\alpha}\sim \operatorname{Multinomial}(n, \v{p})\right]\mathclose{}\\
&= \sum_{\lvert\v\alpha\rvert = n} \binom{n}{\v\alpha} \v{p}^\v{\alpha} \mathbb{E} [f(\v{M}\v{X}) \mid \v{X}\sim\v{\nu}^{\otimes \v{\alpha}}],
\end{align}
where $\v{M}$ is a uniformly random $n\times n$ permutation matrix independent of $\v{X}$. This is a polynomial in $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ with degree $n$ and $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ terms, which leads to a brute-force recipe for finding the maximum expectation in the convex hull of $\{\nu_i\}_{i=1}^k$: calculate the $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ conditional expectations, then find the maximum of the polynomial in the standard $k$-simplex.
Let us specialize this, following the construction in the proof of Proposition 4.1, to find the optimal $p$ in a measure of the form $p\delta_0 + (1-p) \nu$. Replace $f$ by the indicator function for $\v{c}^\intercal \v{X} > 0$, where $\v{c} = (-1,-1,-1,2)$. For each $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ (we will be taking $\varepsilon\to0^+$), define $\mu_\varepsilon = p\delta_0 + (1-p) \nu_\varepsilon$ with $p \in [0,1]$ to be optimized, where $\nu_\varepsilon$ is the distribution of the random variable $1-\varepsilon^U$ with $U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ (notice that $\varepsilon^U = e^{U\log\varepsilon}$ is log-uniform distributed, which is a continuous analogue of the discrete uniform distribution with exponential spacing). Then
\begin{align}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{X} > 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \mu_\varepsilon^{\otimes 4}]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\mathopen{}\left[\mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{M}\v{X} > 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \delta_0^{\otimes i}\otimes\nu_\varepsilon^{\otimes 4-i}] \mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(4, p)\right]\mathclose{}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^4 \binom{4}{i} p^i (1-p)^{4-i} \mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{M}\v{X} > 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \delta_0^{\otimes i}\otimes\nu_\varepsilon^{\otimes 4-i}].
\end{align}
As $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, the conditional probabilities
$$\textstyle (\mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{M}\v{X} > 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \delta_0^{\otimes i}\otimes\nu_\varepsilon^{\otimes 4-i}])_{i=0}^4 \to (0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},0),$$
so applying Proposition 3.4 gives the lower bound
\begin{align}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \sup_\mu \mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{X} > 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \mu^{\otimes 4}]\\
&\geq \sup_{p} \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \frac{\mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{X} > 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \mu_\varepsilon^{\otimes 4}]}{1 - \mathbb{P} [\v{c}^\intercal \v{X} = 0 \mid \v{X} \sim \mu_\varepsilon^{\otimes 4}]}\\
&= \sup_p \frac{2p(1-p)^3+3p^2(1-p)^2+p^3(1-p)}{1-p^4}\\
&\approx 0.400695,
\end{align}
which attains its maximum at $p = p_\text{max} \approx 0.474346$.

For Problem 5.2, I wonder if the one-sided limits
\begin{align}
\lim_{c\to 2^+} \sup_\mu \mathbb{P}_{\mu^{\otimes 4}}[X_1+X_2+X_3 <c X_4] \geq 0.482781\\
\lim_{c\to 1^+} \sup_\mu \mathbb{P}_{\mu^{\otimes 4}}[X_1+X_2+X_3 <c X_4] \geq 0.309684
\end{align}
are attained by the measures obtained from applying Proposition 3.4 to a Bernoulli distribution. The lower bounds listed above are from these measures.
Notice that the lower bound for the limit as $c\to 2^+$ exceeds the upper bound for the value at $c = 2$ (and similarly for $c\to 1^+$ and $c=1$, which has the known value 1/4), so the function $c \mapsto \sup_\mu \mathbb{P}_{\mu^{\otimes 4}}[X_1+X_2+X_3 <c X_4]$ is not everywhere continuous on the interval $[1,3]$. Is it known whether this is continuous on $(2,3)$? If not, perhaps Problem 5.3 should ask for
$$\sup\mathopen{}\left\{c_*\in[2,3] \mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} \sup_\mu \mathbb{P}_{\mu^{\otimes 4}}[X_1+X_2+X_3 <c_* X_4] \leq \frac{1}{2}\right\}\mathclose{},$$
since it doesn't seem clear whether 1/2 is necessarily achieved by some $c_*$.

(Added 2024-12-29) Two ideas I am unsure about:

I find it tempting to replace $\varepsilon$ above with an infinitesimal in a non-Archimedean ordered field (à la nonstandard analysis), to simplify calculations by removing the limits.

Given that the surreals form a universal ordered field (in the sense that every ordered field is a subfield), this brings to mind Conway's work on the connection between the surreals and certain combinatorial games, which feels serendipitous because the preprint was already motivating this problem in terms of games! Perhaps we can reframe this problem so that it is games all the way down.



Wow! This is very nice. The same works for our distributions $\mu$ in the proof of Prop 4.1: we can get the same bound by simply choosing weights $p$ and $\frac{1-p}{N}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2N}$. We'll update the paper accordingly (mentioning this as your observation). It seems plausible to me that the value that you've found is actually the optimal one.

The failure of continuity in $c_*$ is interesting as well and certainly something that deserves to be mentioned. As for taking $\varepsilon$ to be infinitesimal, that doesn't technically work because we do want our variables to take values in the real rather than (say) the hyperreals. Combinatorial games in Conway's sense are very different from what we consider a "game" in the paper, so I'm not sure what exactly to say about that.
